# Getting negative numbers in C++

Tags: c++

The question I am trying to solve is Find the thirteen adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product.. I am trying to figure out when i try to read more than 8. It seems like it isn't running anymore.
Right now I get the value of 2145402160 but I want to read 13 values. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? test.txt file is

```
73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450



#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int a,b,c,d,e,g,h,j,k,l,m,n,o,p;
unsigned long long f;
unsigned long long max = 0;
FILE *fp;
fp=fopen("/Users/desktop/test.txt","r");
fscanf(fp,"%1d",&a);
fscanf(fp,"%1d",&b);
fscanf(fp,"%1d",&c);
fscanf(fp,"%1d",&d);
fscanf(fp,"%1d",&e);
fscanf(fp,"%1d",&h);
fscanf(fp,"%1d",&j);
fscanf(fp,"%1d",&k);
fscanf(fp,"%1d",&l);
fscanf(fp,"%1d",&m);
fscanf(fp,"%1d",&n);
fscanf(fp,"%1d",&o);




for(int i=13;i<=1000;i++)
{
    fscanf(fp,"%1d",&p);
    f=a*b*c*d*e*h*j*k*l*m*n*o*p;
    if(max<f)max=f;
    a=b;
    b=c;
    c=d;
    d=e;
    e=h;
    h=j;
    j=k;
    k=l;
    l=m;
    m=n;
    n=o;
    o=p;

}
printf("%lld\n",max);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you include the contents of test.txt in your question?

Comment: I'm not completely sure of what you are trying to do. The negative numbers you get is likely because you went over the max. You could try unsigned long long instead, it doubles  the normal max.

Comment: Doesn't long long solve the negative number issue though

Comment: @drescherjm could you explain why?

Comment: You mention "negative numbers" in the title, but not in the question. What negative numbers are you referring to? Also, the language is called C++, not Cpp; the latter is a common abbreviation for the C preprocessor.

Comment: The modified code works correctly for me now.  If it fails for you then it could be because you have 16-bit int

Comment: @MattMcNabb what value are you getting?

Comment: I get `2571912 = 9*9*8*7*9*7*7`. I see you have changed the code yet again however. In future post the real code the first time.

Answer (score 4):

On this line:

```
f=a*b*c*d*e*h*j*k*l*m*n*o*p;
```

all of the right hand side are ints, so you get integer overflow. You need to do the multiplication in long long precision, e.g.:

```
f= 1ULL * a*b*c*d*e*h*j*k*l*m*n*o*p;
```

Also (now that you have changed to using unsigned long long) you also need to update the format string for printing the result:

```
printf("%llu\n", max);
```

Comment: The next step for you is to learn about a concept called "arrays". Properly using arrays should cut the size of the code by about a half.